# SSH: Connection closed by remote server

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am trying to ssh login to my remote server. But whenever i try to login through terminal using ssh command:

```
  ssh root@{ip_address}
```

I get error:

```
 Connection closed by {ip_address}
```

I checked hosts deny and hosts allow, there is nothing in the file. I am not getting why it happening?

It happened when i changed my workstation and key got changed. When i tried ssh login, it asked to add key and i entered yes and then it closed the connection.

Is there any way to get connected with ssh again?

Your help is appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Output of ssh -v -v -v -v root@{ip_address} is

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to {ip_address} [{ip_address}] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/mona/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/mona/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/mona/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mona/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mona/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mona/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mona/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "{ip_address}" from file "/home/mona/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 151.236.220.15
```

Comment: Please send us the output of `ssh -v -v -v -v root@{ip_address}`

Comment: @IwanAucamp Hey wrote the output in question. Thanks.

Comment: From the man page: `Multiple -v options increase the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.`

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue but a simple remote server reboot helped.

Comment: This helped. Probably its enough to restart the ssh service?

Comment: I don't know why. Maybe some corrupt SSH server state occurred.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure your server is permitting root logins via SSH?
If not, I suggest using a different account with `sudo` privileges instead of enabling root login - especially if the server's SSH port is accessible from the whole inernet.

Comment: good advise for root user -- i implicitly replaced root@ with myuser@, which is what I wanted.  I am confused why ssh on client resolves an issue with the server closing the socket.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to connect with a user, which had `:/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd`. After changing it to `:/bin/bash` the connection was not closed anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue that was resolved by lowering the MTU on the client side with the following command:
`ip li set mtu 1400 dev eth0`

I found this solution from a separate thread on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/210408/cannot-ssh-debug1-expecting-ssh2-msg-kex-dh-gex-reply).

Comment: This fixed it for us, after three of us had wasted hours on it. Wonderfully obscure.

Answer (score 3):

try sudo ssh root@{ip_address}, it works for me.

Comment: While this answer doesn't provide any reasoning for why it worked, it actually does solve one potential cause for the error the OP got, and in fact, solved my issue when I ran into this as well: If you attempt to connect via some user account that isn't allowed or doesn't exist, but root is allowed, then this can solve the issue.

The more general solution at play is simpler: use a user account that exists and is configured for SSH.

Comment: How do I configure account for ssh so that I can connect to it?

Comment: this is a terrible answer you should not need sudo to connect via ssh

Comment: @zwolin  it's configured on the ssh server.  The person that configured the SSH server created the user with normal linux commands to do so. Linux computers have a root user by default.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same "Connection closed by {ip_address}" error on one of my SSH connections. I tried all the usual solutions and nothing worked. Finally I found that the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the host was corrupted. Someone had tried to append a key to the file, but they copied and pasted it with embedded line feeds where each line wrapped at the end. So what should have been one continuous string spanning three lines was actually three separate strings -- one per line. Since the embedded line feed was exactly at the end of the line, it was not apparent from looking at it.

I deleted the offending key and added my own. Then everything worked as expected.

Comment: Me too. I had a problem with the client keys. Deleting them helped.

Answer (score 1):

I temporarily disabled my antivirus firewall and this maybe helped a bit.
Now it suddenly says Shell access is not enabled on yr account! Connection closed.
So I logged into my WHM server.domain_name:2087 and clicked on Modify domain and enabled Shell Access for the website.
(Or ask your host provider to enable SSh for you if you do not have a WHM server)
Login success, it now says:
Last login: 03:37 from *.* [user@whm_domain_name ~]$

Answer (score -1):

I myself had same problems while working with cloud9 editor. Mine was cause from high CPU usage. It would get fine after stopping apache connection.

Answer (score -1):

Check the name being used to connect to the ftp site, its either wrong or multiple names are being sent for uthentication.