# SSH Connection Closed by Port 22

Tags: ssh, terminal, cpanel, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to establish an SSH connection to my CPanel server. I am using my mac to do this. However, after generating the keys and saving/authorizing the public key to the server, I am unable to create an SSH connection.

I promise I've looked at all the other related solutions, such as changing permissions, checking that the key is authorized on the server, etc.

Here are the results:

```
.ssh % ssh -vvv cpanelusername@site.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to site.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to site.com:22 as 'cpanelusername'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 107.180.56.153 port 22
```

After doing a lot of research, I am still confused as to what these debugs mean and why my connection is being closed. If anyone has any insight to why I can't connect or can explain the debugs, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct username and hostname? Is it really called `site.com` and is the user really `cpannlusername`?

Comment: Sorry-- site = the actual domain and cpanelusername = my username. Just switched them out for privacy.

Comment: But even with the correct user name, it's giving you the same logs right?

Comment: Yes, logs are the same

Comment: Are using public /private key author password auth?

Comment: I tried both using keys with a password and keys without

Comment: Do you somehow have a copy of the sshd_conf somewhere? Is the server in the cloud or it's own physically by you?

Comment: I don't. The server is on my CPanel account. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120956/ssh-connection-closed-by-remote-server

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account you are using has records in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group`. Also make sure the homedir exists and is owned by the account.